# Printing number with leading plus to excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of string values I need to print to a worksheet.  They looks like this:

"+1, +2, +3"

"+1"      <- Problem only on this string

"+1, +2, +3, +4"

As you can see these start with a "+".  Excel removes the leading plus on the second string, and moves the number to the right of the cell.

I assume it's treating the string as a number.  The string is concatenated, dimensioned as string type, and even converted (CStr).  How can I force Excel to recognize this as string and print the leading '+'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to keep them as strings, then prefix the whole lot with a leading single quotation character. That forces Excel to use a string type. That is, use

`"'+1"`

instead.

(But if you want them to be numeric, then *format* the region of the Excel workbook appropriately.)

Answer (score 3):

try this to make Excel treat it as a string ="+1"

```
> Dim v As Variant, r As Range
>     Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1")
>     For Each v In Split("+1, +2, +3, +4", ",")
>         r.Formula = "=""" + v + """"
>         Set r = r.Offset(1)
>     Next
```

Comment: Yup this works, upvoted .And a free drink if you can figure out the line of VBA to output that in the next two minutes ;-)

Comment: Can't get the code formatted properly in a comment, added the VBA to the answer